# How to get the sum of the elements of a list?

Tags: python, list, sum

How can I get the sum of the elements of a list?
i.e,

```
f = [1,8,3]
sum(f)=12?
```

Comment: You literally gave the answer with your psuedo-code. Why would you take the time to ask a question on here without just checking if that worked? This is also essentially the first thing in the documentation.

Comment: .. wait, in your last question your code had a line `[sum(item) for item in zip(self.rows[x], mat[x])]`.  What did you think this did?

Comment: why is it, TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'? it appeared like this?

Comment: you must be passing an iterable of lists to `sum`, it's unlikely that's what you intended but you can add lists with sum, if you pass a list as the start parameter `sum(item, [])`

Comment: @ysen07 You have the right to submit your own answer and accept it :)

Comment: @GP89 best not confuse OP, he had the right thing anyway

Comment: @jamylak yea just I guess his actual use case was more complex than in the question, he was saying he was getting `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'`. So this is the problem he needs to address, rather than thinking that `sum` doesn't sum a list of integers - that he's not passing in a list of ints like he thinks he is.

Answer (score 3):

You guessed it,  `sum(f)`. Why didn't you try it?

```
>>> f = [1,8,3]
>>> sum(f)
 12
```